# How to make logical volumes on loopback block device available?

Tags: lvm, loop-device

I have a file `hdd.img` being raw image of a hard disk. The harddisk has a BIOS/DOS partition table and its second partition is setup to serve as a the one single physical volume from which LVM creates logical volumes.

My goal is to access the partitions/filesystems that are represented by those logical volumes.

I setup loopback block device mapping for the `hdd.img` via the command:

```
$ sudo losetup --partscan -f hdd.img
```

which results me seeing the two partitions contained in that image on the loopback device (it was `loop17`)

```
$ lsblk | grep 'loop17'
loop17                7:17   0  30G  0 loop
├─loop17p1          259:4    0   1G  0 loop
└─loop17p2          259:5    0  29G  0 loop
```

The question now is. How can I inform the system to scan /dev/loop17p2 for the logical volumes I actually want to access

**Update**

Installing the package `kpartx` and doing this:

```
$ sudo losetup -f hdd.img
$ sudo kpartx -a /dev/loop17
```

did generate the lvm mappings to the volumes contained on `/dev/loop17p2`. While this solves my immediate needs it would yet still be great to know why `vgscan` does not work once the `losetup --partscan -f hdd.img` had already created the `/dev/loop17p2` block device that contains the logical volumes?

Answer (score 1):

Use `lvscan`. `vgscan` is to scan Volume Group ...

Comment: I tested using `lvscan`, but this has not resulted in any mappings being created. Can you show a how it would be done with the `lvscan`

Answer (score 1):

The command `vgscan` has an command line option `--cache` that must be used to put the the results of the scan into the cache, allowing a subsequent `vgchange -ay <vg>` call to genrete the mapping

In short this work:

```
$ sudo losetup --partscan -f hdd.img
$ sudo vgscan --scan
$ sudo vgchange -ay <vg>
```

whith `vg` being the one of the volume group (which the vgscan) has reported.

This would however **not** work:

```
$ sudo losetup --partscan -f hdd.img
$ sudo vgscan
$ sudo vgchange -ay <vg>
```

because the second command would have not put its scanning results into the `--cache`. Oddly enough my take on the `--cache` flag was to think it meant to use *cached* values instead of performing an actual scan.

Comment: I assume `vgscan --scan` is a typo and it should be `vgscan --cache`?